# Read just like regex but in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, regex, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I want to read some text and get something out from it.

I have this text:

```
/FILES/Project/1611\1/thumbs/8dff051e-ff77-4540-ae4b-f643960bbdad_logo.png.80x80.jpg
```

And I want to get that number before thumbs as you can see **\1/** but inside stored procedure just like we do in C# or javaScript using regex.

How can I do this in a stored procedure?

I surfed the net but not getting any kind of solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the patindex and substring function for this.

Code below works for the given example.

```
Declare @txt varchar(max) = '/FILES/Project/1611\1/thumbs/8dff051e-ff77-4540-ae4b-f643960bbdad_logo.png.80x80.jpg'

select SUBSTRING(txt,startPosition,EndPosition-StartPosition)
from
(
    select PATINDEX('%/thumbs/%',@txt) endPosition,patindex('%\%',@txt)+1 StartPosition, @txt txt
)p
```